# custom RSS : list tags in xml

Tags: drupal, rss, tags, view

For an iphone app I'm writing, I'd like to be able to list the tags used on my drupal site.
I'd like to have an url i could call from iphone to receive an xml list of tags used on the drupal site currently.

May I do it with Drupal views ? any idea how to do that.
The idea is that i'll cal back from iphone to another custom rss feed to list the article binded to that tag.

...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with views.

Create a view that displays taxonomy terms in your tag directory.  Create a 'Feed' Display, and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

1st - RSS isn't really appropriate for this. Since you are looking for a representation of tags, not articles. 
Using the services module is a better solution than just views since you get authentication, and once the connection is setup you can do more with the drupal site.

Using the json module with services we were able to make this work much better than when we first tried to output xml using views.